# como puedo activar submenu con jquery? el primer nivel funciona bn

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap

el menu funciona bn pero cuando le doy click al segundo nivel , del menu no funciona y me cierra el menu completo

```
   
    Información institucional
        
            Perfiles Directivos y Organigrama
                
                    Organigrama
                    Despacho Superintendente de Industria y Comercio
                    Delegaturas
                        
                            Delegatura para la Protección del Consumidor
                        
                    
                    Oficinas
                        
                            Oficina Asesora Jurídica
                        
                    
                    Direcciones
                        
                            Dirección de Signos Distintivos
                        
                    
                    Estudios Económicos
                
            
            Entidades sector Comercio, Industria y Turismo
```

```
esto es el query 

jQuery('ul>li').click(function(){
           jQuery("ul>li>ul").toggle();

           jQuery(this).children('ul>li>ul').slideToggle();
           jQuery(this).toggleClass("active");
     });
```

```
esto es el css
.menu-lateral-sic ul>li.active {

    border-top: none!important;
    border-bottom: none!important;
    background-size: 0.7rem!important;
     background: url(https://www.sic.gov.co/sites/default/files/images/2019/sic_home_enlaces/iconos/menos-icono-menu.png) no-repeat!important;
    background-position-x: 100%!important;
    background-position-y: 13px!important;
    position: inherit!important;

}

.menu-lateral-sic ul>li.menuparent{
     background: url(https://www.sic.gov.co/sites/default/files/images/2019/sic_home_enlaces/iconos/mas-icono-menu.png) no-repeat;
    background-color: white;
    border-top: none;
    background-size: 0.7rem;
    background-position-x: 100%;
    background-position-y: 13px;
    position: inherit!important;
    border-bottom: #888 1px solid;
}
.menu-lateral-sic ul>li>ul>li.active:hover {

    border-top: none!important;
    border-bottom: none!important;
    background-size: 0.3rem!important;
     background: url(https://www.sic.gov.co/sites/default/files/images/2019/sic_home_enlaces/iconos/flecha-azul-icono-menu.png) no-repeat!important;
    background-position-y: 50%!important;
    position: inherit!important;
    display: block;

}

.menu-lateral-sic ul>li>ul>li.menuparent{
     background: url(https://www.sic.gov.co/sites/default/files/images/2019/sic_home_enlaces/iconos/flecha-azul-icono-menu.png) no-repeat;
    background-color: white;
    border-top: none;
    background-size: 0.3rem;
    background-position-y: 50%;
    position: inherit!important;
    padding-left: 10px;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: la base del codigo es

Comment: Hola, ¿podrías poner el HTML para hacer el ejemplo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hice un ejemplo lo mas sencillo posible, lo hice sin estilos y despues tu le aplicas los tuyos propios.

Ejemplo script JS con Jquery:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.button-dropdown').click(function() {

            $(this).siblings('.dropdown').toggle();

        });
    });
</script>
```

Lo que hace el script es hacer referencia a la clase CSS llamada button-dropdown que al darle click en el propio elemento busca al elemento hermano con la clase CSS llamada dropdown y al elemento le aplica la función toggle().

Ejemplo, snippet para que lo pruebes (La estructura la pillé de lo que publicaste):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .dropdown {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .button-dropdown::after {
      content: "▼";
      padding-left: 8px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="button-dropdown"> Información institucional</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="button-dropdown">Perfiles Directivos y Organigrama</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
              <li>
                <a href="#">Organigrama</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Despacho Superintendente de Industria y Comercio</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="button-dropdown">Delegaturas</a>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Delegatura para la Protección del Consumidor</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="button-dropdown">Oficinas</a>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Oficina Asesora Jurídica</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="button-dropdown">Direcciones</a>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Dirección de Signos Distintivos</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Estudios Económicos</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Entidades sector Comercio, Industria y Turismo</a></li>

        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('.button-dropdown').click(function() {

        $(this).siblings('.dropdown').toggle();

      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Nota: apliqué dos Clases CSS para crear los dropdown.

Comment: gracias funciono